# How does foreach work on a list with 2d arrays as elements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project I have a List with 2d string arrays as elements inside of that list:

```cs
List<string[,]> listOfLists = new List<string[,]>()

//the array has a variable amount of rows and 3 columns
```

It basically holds some arrays that I need to save. Now, to control if everything is working, I want to put it in a *foreach-loop* and output everything that was saved, but it just returns the 3rd column of the array saved in `listOfLists[0]`

```
    foreach(string smth in listOfLists[0])
    {
        return smth;
    }
```

I put that *foreach-loop* inside `override .ToString()` (`Debug.Log(xxx.ToString())`) and I know it should work returning a `string[,]` as string but it does and it returns the 1st column, so if the array is defined like this:

```cs
listOfLists[0][0, 0] = "A";
listOfLists[0][0, 1] = "B";
listOfLists[0][0, 2] = "C";

listOfLists[0][1, 0] = "D";
listOfLists[0][1, 1] = "E";
listOfLists[0][1, 2] = "F";
```

it JUST returns A and NOT B, C, D, E or F.

I can output it like this, so the array isn't not working or anything:

```cs
return $"{listOfLists[0][0, 0]} geht in die {listOfLists[0][0, 2]} und ihr Foto ist aufzufinden bei: {listOfLists[0][0, 1]}";
```

I just think its more practical to put it in a *foreach-loop*, than to call everything by it's own.

I know I did something wrong on the *foreach-loop* but I don't know, what it is or how to solve it.

My goal is to return the whole array like that:

```cs
//return
A B C D E F
```

Edit: I've tried it in just a c# script like this

´´´

public class Fun
{

private List<string[,]> listOfLists = new List<string[,]>();

```
    public void declareList()
    {
        listOfLists.Add(new string[2, 3]);

        listOfLists[0][0, 0] = "A";
        listOfLists[0][0, 1] = "B";
        listOfLists[0][0, 2] = "C";

        listOfLists[0][1, 0] = "D";
        listOfLists[0][1, 1] = "E";
        listOfLists[0][1, 2] = "F";

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string _smth = "";
        foreach(string smth in listOfLists[0])
        {
            _smth += smth;
        }

        return _smth;
    }
}
```

´´´

and it works; it returns ABCDEF.
I even found the mistake from above; return breaks the whole foreeach-loop, so it can't finish up. Thats why it was just returning A.

I think one comment mentioned that it's strange that I can implie a string as a string[] while declaring the foreach-loop, but I think that is just because when the foreeach-loop is executed it's a string and not a string[]. I hope everyone can unsterstand it.

Comment: Maybe add some sample data too... like what your inputs are, what your output is, and what you expect your output to be?

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't get an error putting a `string[,]` into a `string` variable in your `foreach` declaration there, but that's your problem.

Comment: inputs: marie, /user/..., 32f
output: 32f
expectect output: marie /user/... 32f
is that enough?

Comment: @logarr idk either. But instead if I do `string[,] smth in listOfLists[0]` it gives me an error. I'll therefore no one can solve this, just do it by manually outputting the array.

Comment: If you provide me with the example of what you want to output from your loop I can show you what you did wrong. The solution is going to depend entirely on what your goal is though.

Comment: @Logarr what do you expect type element in foreach of 2d array would be? ("I don't know why you wouldn't get an error putting a string[,] into a string variable"). Clearly `foreach` iterates through all items in a sequence just fine... Even OP claim "just returns the 3rd column" which (while being totally bogus) indicate that code compiles fine and runs to some extent.

Comment: if you `return` within the `foreach` loop .. well you will only return the very first element ...

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is that the foreach you wrote is trying to iterate over strings, while your actual contents in the list are string *arrays*.

Here's an example that compiles and runs on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Omosen) that shows how you could iterate over the structures you have declared. Also posting code here for posterity.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        List<string[,]> arrayList = new List<string[,]>();
        var twoDArray = new string[5,5];
        // just a couple of items for testing, intentionally leaving some indices null as well
        twoDArray[0,0] = "a";
        twoDArray[0,1] = "b";
        twoDArray[0,2] = "c";
        
        twoDArray[1,0] = "d";
        twoDArray[1,1] = "e";
        twoDArray[1,2] = "f";
        
        arrayList.Add(twoDArray);
        arrayList.Add(twoDArray);
        
        foreach(var array in arrayList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("=== Starting iterration for another array in the array list ===");
            // iterates over the array as flattened items
            foreach(var arrayItem in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Flattened iteration - value {0}", arrayItem));
            }
            
            // or you can iterate over the items with their indices
            for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(0); x += 1) 
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(1); y += 1) 
                {
                    var indexedItem = array[x,y];
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Indexed iteration - at index {0},{1} value {2}", x, y, indexedItem));
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more trail-and-error-testing I've come up with this version:

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    string test = "";

    foreach(string smth in listOfLists[0])
    {
        test += smth;
    }

    return test;
}
```

It magically works, what I find pretty interesting, because I've had some tries in which *test += smth* did not work for some reason and it would show me a strange error message  in Unity. But I'll not question why it's magically working as wished.

Still thank you for answering the question.